# Regex Expression to match mysql_result parameters

Tags: php, regex

I need to use a regex to find method to do this.

For example I have two functions:

```
mysql_result($one,"val1")
mysql_result($two,0,"val2")
```

How can I write a regex to find only first function?

Currently I have`(mysql_result\()(.*),(.*)(\))` but this matches two functions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `.*` matches as much text as possible -- it is so called "greedy".

Although you can do `.*?` in many regex engines to make it match as little as possible, it wouldn't necessarily help here.

I say you should use the following syntax to "match anything until specified character", here until comma or closing parenthesis:

```
mysql_result\([^,]*,[^,)]*\)
```

(I also removed the extra parentheses, they are not needed unless you want to capture some parts for search & replace etc.)